# How to compare timing?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a function to compare with the estimated time and actual time.

if estimated time = actual time + 15 minutes
 return delay

for example: 
estimated time = "09:00"
actual time = "09:15" late

How can i do it in android java ?

Comment: What you have tried so far? You can compare time using milliseconds.

Comment: check the `LocalTime`  class, it has methods like `isAfter()` and `compareTo` for that: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html)

Comment: Use `LocalTime` and `Duration` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution to be able to use parameters easily is to use `Duration`.

You can get the duration between to "time". From this, you can easily check of this is in a valid delay or not comparing two `Duration`.

Using `Duration.between` with two `LocalTime`, you will get the duration between the two. Then you just need to compare this with a specific duration of time, something like this :

```
//Our times for this test.
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.of(9, 10);

//A duration of 15minutes, used to validate the difference between the two times
Duration delay = Duration.ofMinutes(15);

//A duration between two times  
Duration d = Duration.between(lt1, lt2);
//Is less than, or equal to the duration.
boolean isValid = d.compareTo(delay) <= 0;
```

Using :

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
```

A more complete test code

```
    LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.of(9, 0);
    LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.of(9, 10);
    LocalTime lt3 = LocalTime.of(9, 15);
    LocalTime lt4 = LocalTime.of(9, 20);

    Duration delay = Duration.ofMinutes(15);
    System.out.format("%s and %s as more than %s delay : %s%n", lt1, lt2, delay, Duration.between(lt1, lt2).compareTo(delay));
    System.out.format("%s and %s as more than %s delay : %s%n", lt1, lt3, delay, Duration.between(lt1, lt3).compareTo(delay));
    System.out.format("%s and %s as more than %s delay : %s%n", lt1, lt4, delay, Duration.between(lt1, lt4).compareTo(delay));
```

Output :

> 09:00 and 09:10 as more than PT15M delay : -1
>   09:00 and 09:15 as more than PT15M delay : 0
>   09:00 and 09:20 as more than PT15M delay : 1

You can easily use different `Duration` values and it is not complicated to get a `LocalTime` from a `String`, a `LocalDateTime` or even a `Date`.

Comment: Doesn’t it require Android API level 26 or higher? No, it doesn’t. `LocalTime` and `Duration` are part of java.time, and java.time has been backported, so on earlier Android use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (ABP for Andoird Backport). See the details in [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void compareTime(String lastTime) {

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);
            String currentTime = format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            Date date2 = null;
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = format.parse(lastTime);
                date2 = format.parse(currentTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert date2 != null;
            long difference = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 1000;
            long hours = difference % (24 * 3600) / 3600; // Calculating Hours
            long minute = difference % 3600 / 60; // Calculating minutes if there is any minutes difference
            long min = minute + (hours * 60);
            if (min > 24 || min < -24) {

            }

}
```

Your lastTime should be in "hh:mm:ss aa" this format as same to currentTime.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).